# Python Basics – slicing a long string and combine the sliced in wanted pieces

Tags: python, list

Environment: Win 7; Python 2.76

Hello all…I need to pick up some texts from a string, which looks like:

“C-603WallWizard45256CCCylinders:2HorizontalOpposedBore:1-1/4Stroke:1-1/8Length: SingleVerticalBore:1-111Height:6Width:K-720Cooling:AirWeight:6LBS1.5H.P.@54500RPMC-60150ccGasEngineCylinder:4VerticalInlineBore:1Stroke:1Cycle:4Weight:6-1/2LBSLength:10Width: :AirLength16Cooling:AirLength:5Width:4L-233Height:6Weight: 4TheBlackKnightc-609SteamEngineBore:11/16Stroke:11/16Length:3Width:3Height:4TheChallengerC-600Bore:1Stroke:1P-305Weight:18LBSLength:12Width:7Height:8C-606Wall15ccGasEngineJ-142Cylinder:SingleVerticalBore:1Stroke:1-1/8Cooling:1Stroke:1-1/4HP:: /4Stroke:1-7/:6Width:6Height:9Weight:4LBS1.75H.P.@65200RPM”

The wanted are:

I.  Combinations of 1 letter + 3 numbers, joint by ‘-’. Such as: C-603, K-720, C-606 etc

II. Combinations of 5 continuous numbers. Such as: 45256, 54500, 60150, 65200 etc

My idea is to:

1. slice the string into every pieces, like ‘C’, ‘-’, ‘6’, ‘0’, ‘3’, … ‘R’, ‘P’, ‘M’
2. combine them into 4 digits and 5 digits, like ‘C-60’, ‘-603’, ‘603W’… and ‘C-603W’, ‘-603W’ , ‘603Wa’
3. pick up the ones fits the criteria I and II

sounds like a way? If yes, what commands I can use in the processes?
Thanks.

Comment: This is definitely a job for [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going with [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) is one way to do it:

```
>>> data = '''C-603WallWizard45256CCCylinders:2HorizontalOpposedBore:1-1/4Stroke:1-1/8Length: SingleVerticalBore:1-111Height:6Width:K-720Cooling:AirWeight:6LBS1.5H.P.@54500RPMC-60150ccGasEngineCylinder:4VerticalInlineBore:1Stroke:1Cycle:4Weight:6-1/2LBSLength:10Width: :AirLength16Cooling:AirLength:5Width:4L-233Height:6Weight: 4TheBlackKnightc-609SteamEngineBore:11/16Stroke:11/16Length:3Width:3Height:4TheChallengerC-600Bore:1Stroke:1P-305Weight:18LBSLength:12Width:7Height:8C-606Wall15ccGasEngineJ-142Cylinder:SingleVerticalBore:1Stroke:1-1/8Cooling:1Stroke:1-1/4HP:: /4Stroke:1-7/:6Width:6Height:9Weight:4LBS1.75H.P.@65200RPM'''

>>> one_letter_three_numbers = re.compile(r'.\-\d{3}', re.IGNORECASE)
>>> re.findall(one_letter_three_numbers, data)
['C-603', '1-111', 'K-720', 'C-601', 'L-233', 'c-609', 'C-600', 'P-305', 'C-606', 'J-142']

>>> five_continuous = re.compile(r'\d{5}', re.IGNORECASE)
>>> re.findall(five_continuous, data)
['45256', '54500', '60150', '65200']
```

Comment: by the way, shaktimaan. is there a way to tell if a string is a word or number? for example, 'cat' is purely a combination of letters; '123' is a number etc..

Comment: @MarkK Explore the function `isdigit()`

`>>> s = 's12'
>>> s.isdigit()
False
>>> s = '123'
>>> s.isdigit()
True`